# Getting `ResourceNotFound` error for files within the `resources/` directory

Tags: rust, ggez

I'm trying to add a spritesheet to my Ggez game, and getting the following error when running `cargo run`:

```
Error: ResourceNotFound("/sprites.png", [("/home/pablo/Dev/rust-game/target/debug/resources", IOError(Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" })), ("/home/pablo/.local/share/our_game", IOError(Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" })), ("/home/pablo/.config/our_game", IOError(Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }))])
```

From [the docs](https://docs.rs/ggez/latest/ggez/filesystem/index.html) I thought I just had to put my sprites.png in the `resources` folder, which I did:

```
❯ ls resources/
sprites.png
```

But it doesn't seem to be looking in that folder, instead it looks in `.../target/debug/resources`. I guess that makes sense, as that seems to be the folder where the build is placed (I'm new to rust, so just taking a guess here). That folder does not exist:

```
❯ ls target/debug/resources
ls: cannot access 'target/debug/resources': No such file or directory
```

For gezz I found `cargo-resource-root` but that option no longer exists it seems. And for Rust the `include` field in `Cargo.toml` also didn't actually make any difference. Are there other things I can try to either let Ggez know to look in the right place, or to let Rust know to include those files?

Comment: The docs to the page you link mention "The resources/ subdirectory in the same directory as the **program executable**, if any,", which would be `target/debug/`. Seems like an odd behavior for a game engine though.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!

It's possible to manually add additional folder it looks for for resources, and the docs mention this can be useful for debugging. So I did [what the docs told me](https://docs.rs/ggez/latest/ggez/filesystem/struct.Filesystem.html#method.mount), and added the following in my `main()`:

```rust
let resources_dir = env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR").to_owned() + "/resources";
context.fs.mount(Path::new(&resources_dir), true);
```

That seems to have worked, at least it's not crashing any more saying it can't find the file.